# How to develop in Android Studio inside VM, but launch parallel VM with Android?

Tags: android, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm in a situation where I need to develop in Android Studio inside a KVM running Ubuntu. I know I can redirect the USB of my phone inside this VM and upload the apks to my phone. But how can I launch a VM parallel to my ubuntu VM? (I'm trying to avoid launching the Android VM inside the Ubuntu VM, so I want to load the Android VM in the same host as my Ubuntu running Android Studio).

If I simply launch an Android on KVM parallel to my Ubuntu in KVM with Android Studio, how to connect the 2? I think this will require some tweaks, like, is it possible to make the Android virtual machine answer adb commands like an USB device and then redirect this usb device into the ubuntu virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADB allows devices to be connected over TCP/IP, in addition to the default USB option. You need your Ubuntu and Android VMs inside the same virtual network, Developer options enabled in your Android VM, root access to your Android VM, and you need to know your Android VM's IP address (say a.b.c.d).

As root in your Android VM, execute the following commands in a shell:

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

You may now connect to your Android VM from Ubuntu. Execute:

```
adb connect a.b.c.d
```

And then execute your required commands, like you would do when a device is connected over USB.

Comment: do you know where to download android image and how to set up virtual manager to run it? Do I have to download arm or amd64?

Comment: http://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/ This site contains **x86** images of the Android OS.

Comment: but how can I download the origina onde that android studio uses?

Comment: Can't get what you're trying to say.. could you make it a bit more clear? BTW google is your friend.

Comment: Android Studio has an 'official' android x86 and amd64 images that it downloads automatically when I create VMs. Where can I find them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439900/2347061